# Change size of specific set of vertices in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph with over 2000 vertices, and I would like to change the size of around 25 of them.  I know that I can specify the size of each of them individually, but I would like to be more efficient. I want something like the following to work, but it doesn't ...
VertexSize -> {{1, 22, 53, 84, 105} -> 6}
(Note that this example would like to make vertices 1, 22, 53, 84, 105 a size of 6.)  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please include a sample of your data and full code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: try `VertexSize -> {Alternatives@@{1, 22, 53, 84, 105} -> 6}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).

```
Thread[{1, 22, 53, 84, 105} -> 6]
(* {1 -> 6, 22 -> 6, 53 -> 6, 84 -> 6, 105 -> 6} *)
```